# Adding binary secret data to a Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to create a Helm chart for a service that has binary secrets.  Currently, we import those secrets using `kubectl`:

`kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-file=fileContainingBinaryData`

To convert this to a Helm chart, I am using a YAML file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: Opaque
metadata:
  name: my-secret
data:
  my-secret: |
    {{- .Files.Get "files/fileContainingBinaryData" | nindent 4 }}
```

However, this results in the following error from Helm:

`Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: YAML parse error on my-service/templates/my-secret.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid leading UTF-8 octet`

This error is presumably due to the fact that the secret contains binary data.  How can this file be incorporated into a Helm chart?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to base64-encode the data.  The YAML file is now:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: Opaque
metadata:
  name: my-secret
data:
  my-secret: {{ .Files.Get "files/fileContainingBinaryData" | b64enc }}
```